# latexdiff: marking whole block as changed

Tags: latexdiff

When I rewrite a paragraph (but keeping a few sentences or equations the same) I would like to mark the whole block as changed so it appears in the diff as one whole block in strike-through-red and then another in underlined-blue (rather than a lot of back and forth).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If the paragraph is simple (i.e. something that would work as argument of a \parbox), then simply surrounding the block with \DIFadd{..} might work. If it's more complicated (e.g. with equations), then the same strategy but using -t CFONT option might work (no more underlining and striking out then, though)